# How to include the Catch block in code coverage : JaCoCo and Junit

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, jacoco

I'm quite new to Junit and JaCoCo. I'm trying to **add test case for the catch block**. But my JaCoCo code coverage is still asking me to cover the catch block in code coverage.
Following is my method and testcase.

```
public Student addStudent(Student Stu) throws CustomException {
    try {
        // My Business Logic
        return Student;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new CustomException("Exception while Adding Student ", e);
    }
}

@SneakyThrows
@Test
public void cautionRunTimeException(){
    when(studentService.addStudent(student)).thenThrow(RuntimeException.class);
    assertThrows(RuntimeException.class,()-> studentService.addStudent(student));
    verify(studentService).addStudent(student);
}
```

[image]

Please share me the correct way for the code coverage of catch block.

Note: JaCoCo version: 0.8.5, Junit version; junit5, Java version: 11

Answer (score 2):

Your `cautionRunTimeException` test doesn't make much sense because currently the whole `studentService#addStudent` method is mocked. So `()-> studentService.addStudent(student)` call doesn't execute real method in `studentService`.

If you want to test `studentService` it mustn't be mocked.   You rather need to mock part of `My Business Logic` section to throw the exception.

Just an example:

```java
    public Student addStudent(Student stu) throws CustomException {
        try {
            Student savedStudent = myBusinessLogic.addStudent(stu);
            return student;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new CustomException("Exception while Adding Student ", e);
        }
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    @Test
    public void cautionCustomException(){
        when(myBusinessLogic.addStudent(student)).thenThrow(RuntimeException.class);
        assertThrows(CustomException.class, ()-> studentService.addStudent(student));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Petr Aleksandrov for the quick response, If I didn't mock the StudentService I can't to use the when() of Mockito. And also I'm unable to make the business logic as failed because its calling an external functionality.

Comment: Again. If you want to test StudentService you must NOT mock it. To test that catch block the exception needs to be thrown somewhere in your 'business logic'.